# Test metodo de modelo Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test, rspec

Estoy intentando realizar el test del metodo 'my_turns', que verifica los turnos de una persona(afiliado). El metodo se encuentra en el modelo de 'Turns'. He intentado lo siguiente pero nose si es correcto:

Mi modelo tiene el siguiente metodo:

```
def self.my_turns(affiliate, fecha)
  Turn.joins(:affiliate).where('code LIKE ? AND canceled = ? AND date_turn >= ?', "%#{affiliate}%", false, fecha).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Y en mi test he intentado lo siguiente:

```
it 'grupo familiar tiene turnos?' do
  turn = create(:turn)
  turn.affiliate_id = 2221
  turn.date_turn = Date.today
  expect(Turn.my_turns(turn.affiliate_id, turn.date_turn)).to be true    
end
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
    Failure/Error: expect(Turn.my_turns(turn.affiliate_id, turn.date_turn)).to be true
     expected true
          got #<Turn::ActiveRecord_Relation:70186851007400> => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu prueba estás buscando que el resultado de `my_turns` sea `true`, mientras que el resultado de `my_turns` siempre será una colección (vacía en el ejemplo que compartes); esto ocasionará que tu prueba siempre falle, te recomiendo utilizar el matcher `be_empty`.

Si por `true` estás buscando que sí haya resultados (i.e. que la colección no esté vacía), entonces utiliza esta línea en su lugar:

```
expect(Turn.my_turns(turn.affiliate_id, turn.date_turn)).no_to  be_empty
```

De igual forma esta prueba fallará pero porque estarás probando que el resultado de `my_turns` sí tenga información. Si tu expectativa es que no regrese vacío, entonces debes modificar tu método o cambiar el *setup* de la prueba.